# automation of tasks - email using web application

Tags: linux, web, automation, cron

I have a web application that monitors farms in certain areas. Right now I am having a problem of performing automation with some of the tasks.

Users of the web application can send reports or checkins using keywords. If the reports or checkins correspond to certain keywords, for example "alert", I need the web application to send an alert to the user via email using that web application. But that alert must be sent two weeks after the date of the report received, and to that particular user only.

Would it be possible to use cron to perform this? If not, can anyone suggest me a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach you might consider is to store an entry in a database for each of these reminder emails you need to send, at the time your user does whatever action in your application that determines the need to send that email exists.  Include the recipient, the date to be sent, and the email content as content you store for each entry.  Schedule a single cron job to run periodically to process these database records by due date, and populate an email template to be sent out.  You can then either delete the database records, or a better option, include a column that indicates they were sent and mark them as sent.

It would help to provide which technology stack you're operating on and what the application is developed in.  Others might be able to point you to technology specific approaches or pre-built plugins/extensions that already do this for the situation you're in, to help you avoid the need to write your own code for the solution.

Comment: Hello. I'm using the Ushahidi platform, which is mainly php and JavaScript. The deployment is set up in a Linux server.

Comment: If you're not using a database, then you could still use the approach I listed, but simply work with a file on the server, writing to it as these events occur, and reading that file with a script invoked via cron.